# Why NSView is not be the given Size?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am making a nsview and given the size but it does nothing and it is small, here the code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        window.styleMask = [.titled, .fullSizeContentView]
        window.backingType = .buffered

        let blueView: NSView = NSView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)))
        blueView.wantsLayer = true
        blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor

        window.contentView = blueView

        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }
    
}
```

As you can see I gave the view the needed size but I cannot set the size for window, because window is container for my nsview, given needed size for nsview should be all it was needed but it does not work! I am using a main file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually set the frame of the window, e.g.

```
window.setFrame(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)), display: false)
```

Just giving the content view a size when you create it isn't enough because as soon as you set it as the content view, it is resized to fit the window instead. This is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419160-contentview).

> The window retains the new content view and owns it thereafter. The view object is resized to fit precisely within the content area of the window. You can modify the content view’s coordinate system through its bounds rectangle, but you can’t alter its frame rectangle (its size or location) directly.